# Word merge syntax

Tags: cognito-forms

So I have been having a blast developing user friendly forms to fill out rather arduous documents lately, but as I have been experimenting with repeating sections, getting them to import properly has been a challenge. So I was hoping you could walk me through the correct syntax for referencing repeating forms in a word doc. The help document was not as helpful as I would like as there were no examples of the type of work I was doing. I have attempted to use calculation language here, but again...errors.

I am fully aware that this is on me, but I was hoping someone here could help me understand.

I need the information in the word table to correspond to the repeating section credits in order of entry. So line one is Item 1 etc. The Item label in the form is `-`, if it matters, and the fields are called `name` (for name) and `how` for relationship.

Please see the attached pictures for reference:

[image: WA100009 first question example]

[image: WA100009 second question example]

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to populate a table based on repeating section data, try including the {each Credit} and {end each} tags within the table itself, like so:

[image]

When you merge your document with an entry, the table should then fill in row by row based on the repeating data:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried to do what you showed, but rather than vertical rows of successive information, I get all the names in the left column and all the relationships in the right column both in a single row. [link]http://imgur.com/a/OXMLA   So I am not entirely sure how to filter it per row. Still working!

Comment: Would you mind submitting a help request here? https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/ I can take a closer look at your document from within our support desk. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I got it. It seems the repeating section doesn't like to auto populate vertically in order like the table does. I used the following Syntax to solve the problem. {each Credits.Where(ItemNumber=”1”)}Name: {N}  {end each}